# What is this pattern called? Run finally?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a name for this pattern? I've written this kind of thing a few times in JavaScript and recently found myself writing it in C#. Thing is, I expect this has already been implemented in a library somewhere I didn't know what to look for.

In pseudo code it's something like this:

```
if (null != referenceToPreviousRequest) {
    referenceToPreviousRequest.cancel();
}

referenceToPreviousRequest = setTimeout(function() {
    //The thing I ultimately want to do
}, 1000 /*The delay after the last request*/);
```

Typically I use this kind of code in client side JavaScript, for delaying an AJAX request until a certain amount of time after the last user input, e.g. searching.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe are known as JavaScript Promises, in general programming parlance they are called [Continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). C# supports them through the Task Parallel Library and Async/Await keywords.

Here's how it works, I want to call an operation asynchronously. If the operation is already declared Async it's simple:

- Add async to your function that is calling the existing async function
- Change the return value to Task (for void) or Task (for any other type T)
- Place the keyword await in front of the call to that async function. And follow that call with the rest of my function's logic.

Here's an example (taken from [MSDN Docs on Async Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)).

```
// Three things to note in the signature: 
//  - The method has an async modifier.  
//  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)
//    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer. 
//  - The method name ends in "Async."

async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
    // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
    // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete. 
    //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.  
    //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask. 

    string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");

    // The return statement specifies an integer result. 
    // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value. 
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Reading the linked article will describe what's happening in the background.

You can also explicitly perform continuations in [C# using the ContinueWith operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: According to [this EMCAScript draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects), future versions of Javascript will probably have native promise support.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not convinced. I'm aware of promises, but the key part of the pattern I'm describing is multiple invocations/requests but only one actual run, after a set delay after the last invocation. While this can be built with promises it's not intrinsic to the concept of promises, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Oh and crucially, I don't care about the result of the operation, just that it happens eventually.